# how can I access the admin page of a WRT54GL that is set as a wireless bridge?

Tags: wireless-networking, wrt54gl

I am working to simplify a network for a client.
One part of the network that I am working on is what I believe to be like this:
Netgear Wireless router receives network connection/Internet from VPN router
WRT54GL acts as a wireless bridge to provide a ethernet connection for a office in a part of the building that would be difficult to reach without wireless.

I would like to get into the admin page of the WRT54GL to confirm what I suspect is the setup here.  But the wireless bridge just acts as a pass-through and all I can get to is the wireless bridge of the Netgear wireless router.

Is there a trick to be able to get into the admin page of a wireless router acting as a bridge?

Comment: Don't suppose you ever found the answer did you?